# Combination hangs: Nosetests/multiprocessing/scipy.integrate.ode

Tags: python, scipy, multiprocessing, nosetests

I have a couple of `unittest.TestCase` classes in two separate test files. These two cases are for:

1. [tests/model_test.py]: Testing a model directly - calls the init with various inputs, tests the schema, etc.
2. [tests/multi_run_test.py]: Tests another endpoint which takes arrays of inputs to the model and then uses `multiprocessing` to run many instances of the model in parallel.

If I run `nosetests --verbose` then it runs through the individual model tests just fine but hangs on the multi test. When debugging I can see it get to the `scipy.integrate.ode` "solver" the model uses but then it just hangs there.

Oddly, if I run `nosetests tests/multi_run_test.py` it works just fine.

Any tips or pointers here would be greatly appreciated.